# Pandas Dataframe, want to count values in 3 different colums, accounting for duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a pandas dataframe like this:

| index id | col1 | col2 | col3 | othercolumns ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | apple | orange | nan |  |
| 2 | orange | orange | nan |  |
| 5 | orange | a fruit | nan |  |
| 3 | apple | a fruit | a fruit |  |
| 1 | nan | nan | nan |  |

To count how many times orange, apple, etc occurs in col1, i can simply use groupby and size(). However, if I wanted to count how many times orange, apple, 'a fruit' etc occur throughout the 3 columns, but make sure that i don't double count anything (like counting orange twice in row 2), **how would I do this?** is there a way to concatinate the columns and avoid the duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, which returns `3`. It first checks whether there is at least one orange in each row and then sums up the `True` values:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.eq('orange').any(), axis=1).sum()
```

Thanks to @It_is_Chris, this solution can be improved as follows:

```
(df[df.columns[1:4]] == 'orange').any(axis=1).sum()
```

---

In case the frequencies for all fruits are needed, a solution might be the following:

```
df.iloc[:,1:4].T.agg(pd.unique).explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
orange     3
apple      2
a fruit    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You can avoid the loop by doing `(df[df.columns[1:4]] == 'orange').any(1).sum()` +1

Comment: Thanks, @It_is_Chris, for having commented my answer and for having suggested a very nice alternative way to solve the question! It helps my learning of Python. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can `melt`, `drop_duplicates` and `value_counts`:

```
(df.melt('index id')
   .drop_duplicates(['index id', 'value'])
   ['value'].value_counts()
)
```

output:

```
orange     3
apple      2
a fruit    2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

If `index id` is the index, you can use `stack`:

```
(df.stack().reset_index(name='value')
   .drop_duplicates(['index id', 'value'])
   ['value'].value_counts()
)
```

Another approach, with aggregation to set and `explode`:

```
(df.set_index('index id') # only if not the index already
   .agg(set, axis=1)
   .explode()
   .value_counts()
)
```